# Does F# naming conventions forbids having the same name inside different disc. union types?

Tags: f#

I have a common type in one module and that type is used inside two other discriminated union types.

I named them with the same name because of convenience. Other names are different. Next thing, I am trying to make a helper that prints types in console.

The first line fails to compile because of the type mismatch inside the match-case. I've tried a few things and it still fails with or without opening modules, forcing type and so on.

The other thing is, if I change the manes to Common1 and Common2 it works without any problems.

I remember reading that types with the same signatures are stored inside the same internal type, but my real-life example has different signatures and still fails.

Am I missing a point somewhere?

Example:

Example fails to compile with error:

*Error This expression was expected to have type OneA but here has type OneB*

[image]

```
module commonThings =
    type CommonThing = 
        | Comm1 of int 
        | Comm2 of int 

module thingA =
    open commonThings
    type OneA = 
        | A1 of string
        | Common of CommonThing        
        | A2 of string

module thingB =
    open commonThings
    type OneB = 
        | B1 of string
        | Common of CommonThing        
        | B2 of string

module printAB =
    open commonThings
    open thingA
    open thingB

    let printA (msg:OneA) = 
        match msg with
        | A1 v -> printfn "A1"
        | Common v -> printfn "Common"
        | A2 v -> printfn "A2"

module main =

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 
        printfn "%A" argv
        0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open `thingB` module, type `OneB` comes into scope and the `Common` case label from type `OneA` gets shadowed with the one from type `OneB`.

When name clashes between types or union/active pattern cases occur, the most recent one wins. Reordering the opens would make it work by chance:

```
open thingB
open thingA
```

The right solution is to prefix the case name. There's also `RequireQualifiedAccess` attribute you can use to force a type (or module) to always require prefixes for its internals.

Comment: Also, you could then drop those very granular modules. They don't gain you anything since you open all of them anyway.

Comment: Ok, but it is strange that F#'s type system can't figure it out from implicit declaration in function. I mean.. implementation of of one type hides implementation of other, not related, type.

Comment: What F# does now is pretty straightforward and errors it produces are easy to fix. Making the compiler smarter about it could mean you'll be getting a harder to understand error when something fails to typecheck further down the line. There's always a trade-off involved.

Comment: Also, that's not something that typically comes up in day-to-day coding, at least once you know what to expect.

Answer (score 5):

You can disambiguate by prefixing the type name:

```
let printA (msg:OneA) = 
    match msg with
    | A1 v -> printfn "A1"
    | OneA.Common v -> printfn "Common"
    | A2 v -> printfn "A2"
```